# Not able to execute the sql file script from docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to execute the sql files from docker compose.

My compose file is:

```
    - ../folder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/folder1/
    - ../folder2:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/folder2/
```

The sql files are in folder named folder.

Docker file is:

```
COPY init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
```

init.sh file:

```
"${psql[@]}" -f folder1/*.sql
"${psql[@]}" -f folder2/*.sql
```

I am getting :

**postgres_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/folder1
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
postgres_1  | /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh: line : -f: command not found**

Answer (score 0):

According to mysql image documentation on docker hub:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

Also, the logs show your .sh file is getting executed and got errors. Looking into the code it seems you are trying to execute an init script which execute other *.sql files which is redundant.

If an order of execution is desirable, stick to naming them to comply with an alphabetical order execution.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in the `init.sh` isn't [standard Bourne shell syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html).  I believe that expansion will look for an environment variable named `psql[@]`, and when no environment variable with that name exists (including the punctuation as part of the variable name), you will get an empty string (hence the `-f` option being interpreted as the command).

If you put your SQL initialization files directly in the container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, the container startup will run them for you.  It's reasonable to inject these using a bind mount; you do not need a derived image.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    # Stock PostgreSQL image, not something locally built
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # Bind-mount init scripts directly into init directory
      - ./folder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

If you do want to store these files in the image, `COPY` the SQL scripts (and not the Bourne shell wrapper) into the init directory

```sh
COPY folder/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

You need to do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: I have table structures in both the folders not the data. So i need to mount both the folders somehow to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and alos the folders that i need to mount are not in the same directory as the docker file so directly copying them does not work.

Comment: You might look into whether your application framework has a database migration system you can use.  You'll need this if you ever change the schema, but it can also do this initial setup for you, and it's not Docker-specific.